# Engine damage - repair or replace?

Tags: engine, repair, replace

Accidentally drove over object on road. Turned out to be a tool belt. Oil line cut. I tried to drive to garage, but engine began smoking and car wouldn’t start again after stopping. What
needs repaired?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You aren't really going to know until the engine is inspected. Since the engine stopped, I'm going to assume you ran it out of oil and caused it to seize. If this is the case, more than likely it will need a complete rebuild or engine replacement. Ugly situation, but it's the cold hard truth.

Comment: What make, model and year is the car? What engine do you have in it?